# How to search for an installed app in the Dash when I forgot its name

Tags: 16.04, unity-dash

Can I search for an installed app when I don't remember its name in Ubuntu 16.04? I installed a calculator app (SpeedCrunch). Can I find it by looking for "calculator"?

Comment: Thank you @karel. I don't know why I couldn"t find it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I frequently type only the first letter of an application's name in order to make an application's icon show in the Dash, for example I type `v` to show the VirtualBox icon. I have multiple image editors installed, and I can show them all by typing the *image editor* search term in the Dash search box. I need to add the *editor* search term after the *image* term or else the Dash shows the icon for the Image Viewer app too.

Answer (score 0):

Generally yes. Partial words work too.

Comment: You really should [edit] your answer to provide the "how" part.